# Best practices for multi-user types with Sentry 2 on Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I am planning to make a collaborative website where there are project admins and regular participants which are both users of the site but have separate tables in the database, and I was wondering what was the best approach to make this one.

From online research I found out that the best approach for a regular Laravel 4 Auth system would be to use Morph relationships between user types and main user model. I also found that by duplicating ServiceProvider in Sentry can solve this but I don't think this is a a good practice.

So I was wondering if it is viable to use Morph relationships on Sentry 2, or is there a better practice I am not aware of yet.

Answer (score 0):

The Morph relation seems a good idea to me. It also allows to "extend" Sentry2 aswell as other Eloquent models at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

So what you really need is a polymorphic relationship with the User Model and not the Sentry one since extending Sentry model is a real pain, but there is a hack you can do.

Since User and Sentry models share the same id for a single user you can do the following:

```
User::find(Sentry::getUser()->id)
```

Hope this helps.